# Vaadin Grid Row details not showing in Chrome

Tags: polymer, vaadin-grid

JSBin example:
https://jsbin.com/sofura/3/edit?html,output

*Note this works on jsbin, but not in my local project.

I have an app based on the new Polymer CLI. 
index.html -> main-app.html 
  Uses app-route, contains toolbar, nav, etc.

Another page is defined as a custom element, `<part-info>`.

Within part-info, I have the vaadin-grid setup which includes a nested template for showing the row details.

The row details show up in Edge, but not Chrome.

Is this something to do with nested templates, or perhaps my imports ?

Comment: May have something to do with the flex CSS you have there. See if changing the height to just a fixed value and removing the flex helps.

Comment: On a more style related note, I prefer to keep my row details as an element of its own, makes data binding easier and leads to a cleaner looking result IMO. I made an example of that in one of my tutorial vids https://github.com/vaadin/elementary-school-009/

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks malformed. You have an unclosed `<template>` inside a `<div>` ([line 42](https://jsbin.com/sofura/3/edit?html,output#H:L42)) followed by stray `<div>` and `<template>` tags (starting at [line 63](https://jsbin.com/sofura/3/edit?html,output#H:L63)).

If you enable HTMLHint in your JSBin preferences, you'll see the error:
[image]

<del>But you actually [don't need `<template is="dom-bind">` inside a custom element](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-bind), and that should be removed. Try this modified [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bepufi/edit?html,output) in Chrome.</del> It turns out `<vaadin-grid>` requires an auto-binding template inside the Polymer element to generate the row detail.

Comment: Yea I did apparently copy an extra div close it looks like.

The extra template inside there is for the Vaadin grid row details to use. Notice without it, nothing displays when you click on the rows. 
https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/elements/vaadin-grid/details.html

Comment: I recommend wrapping the row details in a separate component, like here: https://jsbin.com/citagu/2/edit?html,console,output

Comment: @Adam, I just tried your code in Chrome 51 on OS X El Capitan, and it behaves exactly the same as the jsbin (i.e., the row detail appears fine). What's your environment?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  I'm on Win10, but I get the same result on OS X El Capitan.

To be clear, the issue doesn't manifest in the jsbin. It's only when the grid is used within a custom element (page), from another custom element, where the index.html is very basic and just has the "<main-app></main-app>".

I have the row details in another separate component as well, same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the culprit.
    window.Polymer = { dom: 'shadow'};

So it appears that in this case, Edge handles shadow DOM better than Chrome. Or something with the vaadin grid makes it work better with polyfills.

Polymer defaults to shady DOM. Here is a bit more info on shady vs shadow DOM:
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/blog/shadydom